# Xcode: Changing Button Colour

Tags: ios, colors, uibutton, xcode5

I am creating a single view application at the moment in Xcode 5 and I have become stuck. Does anyone know how to make a button change colour depending on what the user does. e.g. I have a button and on depening on which way the user swipes I want to change the colour of the button. So if the button says left and the user swipes left it will go green and if the user swipes right the button will change colour to red. Can someone please help? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

:)

Comment: You need to use gesture recognizers for that. In the particular example, an UISwipeGestureRecognizer will do. But if you need to change the gestures constantly, you'll need to remove the gesture from the view and add a new one for the respective new task. In the selector called from the gestures, change the UIButton's color.

Comment: You are asking two questions here. How do I change a button's color and how do I respond to a gesture. Both of these questions are duplicates. Please do some more searching on StackOverflow and then try to narrow the scope of this question to a specific problem you are having. Showing [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setBackgroundColor. Example:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Create method at header

```
-(void)handleSwipeButton : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) sw;
```

Add bellow code to viewDidload

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeButton:)] autorelease];
swLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:swLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swRight = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeButton:)] autorelease];
swRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:swRight];
```

And add to .m file

```
-(void)handleSwipeButton : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) sw {

if (sw.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    [yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
else
    [yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

}

Comment: I am new to Xcode and I haven't got any idea where to put this code please help @hoptqVN.dev

Comment: Want you swipe on the button?

Comment: Ok. I'm glad cause i helped you. :)

Comment: @Adam Mahmoud. I have just looked you had a question. But it has already deleted. if you have been unsolved, You would posted again and i will help you.

Comment: THANK YOU But I have another question